# Targeting Dashboard relation with Fredhopper Business Manager

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget

We can create Promotions & Experiments in Targeting Dashboard. I am not able to understand what is the purpose of Fredhopper Business Manager here and how is it related to Targeting Dashboard.

Do all Promotion/Experiments created in Targeting Dashboard gets deployed to FredHopper Business Manager ?

What purpose does Business Manager has to play in relation to managing the Promotions? Iam actually confused understanding the concepts here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fredhopper Business Manager is the GUI that comes with Fredhopper. Fredhopper is currently the engine behind Experience Optimization.

You should not use the Business Manager for managing Promotions, though, as that would result in data loss (XO maintains more information about Promotions than the Business Manager is able to). For this reason, Promotions are invisible in the Business Manager by default.

You may still need to use the Business Manager in a few, rare instances -- such as configuring search or navigation facets. But managing Promotions happens wholly within the Targeting dashboard of the SDL Web Content Manager Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to separate is that "Targeting tab" is part of SmartTarget, which is separate from Fredhopper. SmartTarget is SDL module that uses Fredhopper in the background.
So when you create promotions, you create them in SmartTarget. Fredhopper is engine used for indexing content, so in theory you can replace it with different one and still use SmartTarget.
And yes, you should not use Fredhooper to manage promotions, it should be done via targeting tab. You should use fredhopper for mainly configurations like setting live attributes etc...